# The best way to find elements from array and display in input (or select) as a list (one by one) using Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I do not know how to do a simple searching in Angular 6. Let's assume, that is one object with names of company. I want to do this in input/select (what is better?). So, when I click in input/select and write 2/3 characters, function start to search in object (simple mock) or in array. After delete characters, list also disappear.

I do not know if should I use click event or is something special for this.
I want to do this without jQuery.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter several ways. For example for change event or enter:

```
<input pInputText [(ngModel)]="store$.filter.id" (change)="filtering()" (keyup.enter)="filtering()">
```

Of course you have to add a table or list to display found items.